# Where can I find the standard molar entropy for ammonium bicarbonate?

Tags: thermodynamics, reference-request, entropy

I'd like to know the standard molar entropy *S*<sup>0</sup><sub>solid</sub> for ammonium bicarbonate to use in an example in class, to calculate Δ*S*<sup>0</sup> for the reaction, NH<sub>4</sub>HCO<sub>3</sub>(s) → NH<sub>3</sub>(g) + H<sub>2</sub>O(g) + CO<sub>2</sub>(g).

Already checked: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_bicarbonate), [NIST Chemistry WebBook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=ammonium%20bicarbonate&Units=SI), Google. I don't have access to the CRC handbook.

(Arthur and Chester Miller already found the [standard *enthalpy* of formation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61672/enthalpy-of-formation-of-ammonium-bicarbonate) for ammonium bicarbonate, in this forum, in 2016; and it's in the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammoniumhydrogencarbonat).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Standard Thermodynamic Properties of Chemical Substances”, in *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 90th Edition (CD-ROM Version 2010),* David R. Lide, ed., CRC Press/Taylor and Francis, Boca Raton, FL. gives values for the standard molar enthalpy of formation $\Delta_\mathrm fH^\circ$, the standard molar Gibbs energy of formation $\Delta_\mathrm fG^\circ$, and the standard molar entropy $S^\circ$ (all at $T=298.15\ \mathrm K$ and $p=100\ \mathrm{kPa}=1\ \mathrm{bar}$) of crystalline ammonium hydrogen carbonate as follows.
$$\begin{align}
\Delta_\mathrm fH^\circ&=-849.4\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}\\
\Delta_\mathrm fG^\circ&=-665.9\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}\\
S^\circ&=120.9\ \mathrm{J/(mol\ K)}
\end{align}$$